# windows looks strange when wamp server started

Tags: windows, wamp, wampserver, windows-explorer

[image]

Every time when I stated wamp server 2.2e 32bit(Well known for apache,mysql php on windows)  on 64bit windows 7, it changes my Explorer behavior. See the image how the options has gray background color and this color gonna change when mouse hover them.

Please help me out, Is is wamp problem or Tortoise SVN problem. Because After installing Tortoise SVN, It may possible that this problem occurs.

Comment: I have already re-installed the wamp. After the restart of windows 7 it's ok and then again if I started wamp it shows the same problem.

Comment: Just in case you will search for other WAMP I recommend http://open-server.ru/download.html it is stable and very functional (of course portable).